# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when parsing char data

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I need your help.
I have a program to read gps and accelerometer data from port. The programm work like this : when I send 'a' prog will receive gps data and send to database, when I send 'b', prog will send accelerometer data and save to database too. But when I runn the proggram, gps data success to received and send to databse but accelerometer data canot receive and error is "segmentation fault.
Could you help me to resolve the prblem..?

```
int main(void) {

    int fd;
    fd = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open_port: Unable to open port ");
    } else {
        fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
    }

    char a[] = "a";
    char b[] = "b";

    int n,m,cnt;
    char in[30];
    //char in2[50];
    //char *in;
    //char in2[100];
    //in = (char*) malloc(i+1);
    //if (in == NULL) exit(1);


    MYSQL *conn;

    const char *localhost   = "127.0.0.1";
    const char *user     = "root";
    const char *password = "";
    const char *database = "arduino1";

    conn = mysql_init(NULL);

    // Connect to database 
    if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, localhost, user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0))
    {
          fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
          exit(1);
    } 


    for(cnt=0; cnt<5; cnt++) 
    {
        if (cnt < 1) {
            sleep(2);
            n = write(fd, a, sizeof(a));
            printf("Send : %s \n", a);

            //terima data gps dari port
            sleep(1);
            n = read(fd, in, 100);
            if (n < 0)
            {
                perror("read");
                break;
            }

            //query gps         
            char c_lat[50],c_lon[50];
            tokenizer(in,c_lat,c_lon);


            //Isi nilai gps ke database

            char query[255];

            strcat(query,"INSERT INTO gps (latitude, longitude) VALUES (");
                strcat(query,c_lat);
                strcat(query,",");
                strcat(query,c_lon);
                strcat(query,")");

            if (mysql_query(conn, query));
            {
              printf("%s\n", query);
            }


     } else {
            m = write(fd, b, sizeof(b));
            printf("Send : %s \n", b);

            //terima data accelerometer dari port
            sleep(1);
            m = read(fd, in, 100);

            in[m] = '\0';   

            char str[255];

            //query accelerometer   
            char c_nilai_x[10],c_nilai_y[10],c_nilai_z[10],c_teg[6];
            tokenizer_acm(in,c_nilai_x,c_nilai_y,c_nilai_z,c_teg);


            //Isi nilai accelerometer ke database



            strcat(str,"INSERT INTO highcharts_php (x_axis, y_axis, z_axis, tegangan) VALUES (");
                strcat(str,c_nilai_x);
                strcat(str,",");
                strcat(str,c_nilai_y);
                strcat(str,",");
                strcat(str,c_nilai_z);
                strcat(str,",");
                strcat(str,c_teg);
                strcat(str,")");

            if (mysql_query(conn, str));
            {
              printf("%s\n", str);
            }

        }


        // Close database connection
        mysql_close(conn);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Thank you for your help. But I still received the same error. My change is likr this : 
int main(void) {

```
int fd;
fd = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
if (fd == -1) {
    perror("open_port: Unable to open port ");
} else {
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
}

char a[] = "a";
char b[] = "b";

int n,m,cnt;
char in[50];

MYSQL *conn;

const char *localhost   = "127.0.0.1";
const char *user     = "root";
const char *password = "";
const char *database = "arduino1";

conn = mysql_init(NULL);

// Connect to database 
if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, localhost, user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0))
{
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
      exit(1);
} 


for(cnt=0; cnt<5; cnt++) 
{
    if (cnt < 1) {
        sleep(2);
        n = write(fd, a, sizeof(a));
        printf("Send : %s \n", a);

        //terima data gps dari port
        sleep(1);
        n = read(fd, in, 20);
        if (n < 0)
        {
            perror("read");
            break;
        }

        //query gps         
        char c_lat[10],c_lon[9];
        tokenizer(in,c_lat,c_lon);


        //Isi nilai gps ke database

        char query[255] = "INSERT INTO gps (latitude, longitude) VALUES (";
            strcat(query,c_lat);
            strcat(query,",");
            strcat(query,c_lon);
            strcat(query,")");

        if (mysql_query(conn, query));
        {
          printf("%s\n", query);
        }


 } else {
        m = write(fd, b, sizeof(b));
        printf("Send : %s \n", b);

        //terima data accelerometer dari port
        sleep(1);
        m = read(fd, in, 30);

        in[m] = '\0';   



        //query accelerometer   
        char c_nilai_x[8],c_nilai_y[8],c_nilai_z[8],c_teg[4];
        tokenizer_acm(in,c_nilai_x,c_nilai_y,c_nilai_z,c_teg);


        //Isi nilai accelerometer ke database


        char str[255] = "INSERT INTO highcharts_php (x_axis, y_axis, z_axis, tegangan) VALUES (";
            strcat(str,c_nilai_x);
            strcat(str,",");
            strcat(str,c_nilai_y);
            strcat(str,",");
            strcat(str,c_nilai_z);
            strcat(str,",");
            strcat(str,c_teg);
            strcat(str,")");

        if (mysql_query(conn, str));
        {
          printf("%s\n", str);
        }

    }


    // Close database connection
    mysql_close(conn);

}

return 0;
```

}

And the result when I runn the program is :

Send : a 
INSERT INTO gps (latitude, longitude) VALUES (-6.889760,107.619659)
Send : b 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I need help.... Thank you

Answer (score 5):

This is an error:

```
char query[255];
strcat(query,"INSERT INTO gps (latitude, longitude) VALUES (");
```

as [`strcat()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) requires the destination buffer to be null terminated on entry, and it is uninitialized. This means that `strcat()` will search through `query` for a null character and who knows where it will find one, possibly beyond the bounds of `query` which will result in `strcat()` writing to memory it should not be. Change to:

```
char query[255] = "INSERT INTO gps (latitude, longitude) VALUES (";
```

Same error with `str` later in the code.

Instead of using multiple `strcat()` calls use the safer [`snprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

```
char query[255];
int result = snprintf(query,
                      255,
                      "INSERT INTO gps (latitude, longitude) VALUES (%s,%s)",
                      c_lat,
                      c_lon);

/* See following paragraph for explanation of this condition. */
if (result > 0 && result < 255)
{
}
```

`snprintf()` return value (from section *7.19.6.5 The snprintf function* of the C99 standard):

> The snprintf function returns the number of characters that would have been written had n been sufficiently large, not counting the terminating null character, or a negative value if an encoding error occurred. **Thus, the null- terminated output has been completely written if and only if the returned value is nonnegative and less than n.**

Comment: Thank you for you solution. I have try to change like your idea, but I still receive the same error when the program send character [b]. I also try to change number of 100 in read(fd, in, 100) less than char in[30], but still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in the write you need `sizeof(a)+1` to indicate the '\0' termination.

Also you have `char in[30];` but `m = read(fd, in, 100);` 
The amount you read must be less than 30.
when I read http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/strcat.html . I'm wondering if **tokenizer_acm** terminate each parameters with a  '\0'.
by the way if you couldn't use a debugger try setting c_nilai_x, c_nilai_y,c_nilai_z,c_teg with static values.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But when I try that, I still received the same error.